# Shell Script to copy directories from hdfs to local

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

i'm looking for a shell script which should copy directory (with files under) from HDFS to local system.

Comment: hadoop fs -get <path> could easily get the files from hdfs to local.You could add this statement in your shell script

Answer (score 0):

I think it is pointless to write a whole script, when you only need to write one command into terminal. 
With

```
hadoop fs -ls /myDir/path
```

you can verify name and path to directory, which you want to copy and write

```
hadoop fs -get /myDir/path
```

to get file into local. You also can specify destination directory by

```
hadoop fs -get /myDir/path /myLocal/destDir
```

It copies while directory (with subdirectories) to your working directory or to specified directory. You also can get file by file (dir by dir) with

```
hadoop fs -get /myDir/path/*
```

or specific dirs or files in one command

```
hadoop fs -get /myDir/path/dir1 /myDir/path/dir2 .
```

to your directory. I tried it on my Hadoop VM and it works fine.